# How to Edit Apache2.conf | Permission Denied - Amazon AWS (EC2)

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, amazon-ec2, .htaccess

I'm trying upload the edited `apache2.conf` but getting File Permission Denied Error.

```
Status: Starting upload of O:\Users\Circle Radius\SRPL\apache2.conf
Command:    cd "/etc/apache2"
Response:   New directory is: "/etc/apache2"
Command:    put "O:\Users\Circle Radius\SRPL\apache2.conf" "apache2.conf"
Error:  /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: open for write: permission denied
Error:  File transfer failed
```

Comment: Directories /etc and below are owned by root. Are you authenticated with root when upload the config?

Comment: You need to be root in order to edit or move anything in `/etc/` as  @RomeoNinov commented above  , you could try to upload that config in your home directory first and later try to move using sudo mv

Comment: @RomeoNinov I'm accessing it using User - "ubuntu" is there any command which can help me grant the permission for this user so that i can update my apache2.conf directly from FTP

Comment: @ArpitMittal, copy the file to /var/tmp and then via command line move it to the proper place. Do not play with permission in /etc

Comment: @RomeoNinov Thank you so much for you help.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the communication in comments, it is visible you use account which do not have proper permissions to write in `/etc`

The better and more secure way to accomplish your task is:

1. Upload the file (via ordinary user) in `/var/tmp`
2. Login to the terminal
3. Become root: `sudo su -`
4. Make a backup of the original file:

   ```
   cp /etc/apache2/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/apache2.conf_original
   ```
5. Copy the new file:

   ```
   cp /var/tmp/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
   ```
6. Restart apache

Comment: Restart Apache using:  


$ sudo service apache2 restart

Answer (score 0):

Login to the terminal
Become root: `sudo su -`

Make a backup of the original file:

```
cp /etc/apache2/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/apache2.conf_original
```

Copy the new file:

```
cp /var/tmp/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Restart apache

```
<Directory /var/www/html/>
   Options FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Comment: If you don't want to upper process then i suggest you that you can edit this file in nano or vi editor and can edit it. // nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf